# Porque o php não retorna a extensão de todas as imagens ao renomeá-la?

Tags: php

Preciso renomear imagens ao fazer o upload, porém, algumas imagens o código não consegue pegar a extensão para finalizar o processo de maneira correta.

**Fincando assim:** maisguarapari_5c4a3bec18563. (ou seja, salvando a imagem sem a extensão)

Tento diversas vezes com a mesma imagem, mas sem sucesso.

Esta é uma das imagens que não consigo pegar sua extensão pelo código: https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/certo.jpg

Importante lembrar que, tiro fotos pelo meu celular, das dezenas de fotos que faço o envio, **algumas fotos** o código não consegue pegar a sua extensão.

**PHP**

```
$nome = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$extensao = strtolower(end(explode('.', $nome)));
$nomenovoorigem = uniqid('maisguarapari_');
$nomenovo = $nomenovoorigem.".".$extensao;
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="frm_mural" action="/mural-gravar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="entrada_frm_mural" required="required" name="userfile" type="file">
<button class="entrada_frm_mural_enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Qual é o `print_r` do $_FILES quando isso acontece?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss utilizei este código `print_r($_FILES);` e retornou isso `Array ( )`

Comment: Mesmo enviando o arquivo pelo formulário? Pelo resultado parece que nenhum arquivo foi enviado. Aliás, você já não havia feito essa pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, mas em outro contexto. Este caso é bem espefífico.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss faça o teste direto pelo link com o código que o Bulfaitelo enviou https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/teste.php

Comment: O problema de ser bem específico é que acaba se tornando não reproduzível. Recomendo que você edite a pergunta colocando todas as informações possíveis na situação que ocorre o problema, tal como a request que o navegador faz, valores das superglobais no PHP, se tem JS influenciando no upload, logs do servidor, etc.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89057/discussion-between-gladison-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mesmo utilizando exclusivamente o código dele, ou seja, totalmente enxuto, não funciona para pegar a extensão da imagem que disponibilizei o link.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [`pathinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

> **pathinfo** — Retorna informações sobre um caminho de arquivo

```
$path = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$extensao = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$nomenovoorigem = uniqid('maisguarapari_');
$nomenovo = $nomenovoorigem.".".$extensao;
```

**Exemplo Aplicado:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <form class="frm_mural" action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="entrada_frm_mural" required="required" name="userfile" type="file">
        <button class="entrada_frm_mural_enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$path = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$extensao = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$nomenovoorigem = uniqid('maisguarapari_');
$nomenovo = $nomenovoorigem.".".$extensao;

var_dump($nomenovo);
```

Comment: Ainda assim o código não conseguiu pegar a extensão da referida imagem que está acima no link.

Comment: Pois esta imagem no link acima, é uma das diversas fotos que tenho e que o código não consegue pegar a sua extensão.

Comment: No caso a imagem está sendo enviada por um form?, eu vou  montar o ambiente aqui e testar.

Comment: Sim, pelo form.

Comment: Rapais montei seu ambiente aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, vou atualizar o exemplo. testa ai e ve se funciona

Comment: Veja, não funciona para esta imagem https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/teste.php

Comment: Coloquei todo o seu código no link https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/teste.php mesmo assim não funciona. Faça o upload da imagem para voce ver https://www.maisguarapari.com.br/certo.jpg

Comment: Agora entendi o seu problema. Essa imagem tem 7mb; atualiza a pergunta, ou posta aqui o seu php.ini  (a parte de memoria)  com uma imagem menor funciona certamente e configuração do serviço

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89058/discussion-between-gladison-and-bulfaitelo).